# The output halts when entered any positive integer. The problem must be in the while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, execution

```
height=int(input("Enter the height from which the ball is dropped: "))
count=0
travel_dist=0
index=0.6

    if height<=0:
        print("The ball cannot bounce...")
    else:
        while (height>0):
            travel_dist=height+(height*index)
            count+=1
            height=height*index
            if height<=0:
                break;
       print("The ball has bounced ", count, "and travelled the total distance of ", travel_dist)
```

> I have tried removing the while loop but than I cannot get the whole trajectory of the ball.

Comment: Multiplying a positive value repeatedly with 0.6 won't make it zero or negative (mathematically). Due to rounding errors it may become zero if you wait long enough.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is apparently really a math problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

As user @MichaelButscher mentioned above, multiplying a positive value repeatedly with the coefficient (0.6 in this scenario) will get close to zero but will never get there. You can see this if you print out `height` within the while loop. You'll have to set the limit of `height` to a different number (ex: I changed `while (height>0)` to `while (height>2)`)like so:

```
height=int(input("Enter the height from which the ball is dropped: "))
count=0
travel_dist=0
index=0.6

if height<=0:
    print("The ball cannot bounce...")
else:
    while (height>2):
        travel_dist=height+(height*index)
        count+=1
        height=height*index
        print(height)
        if height<=0:
            break
    print("The ball has bounced ", count, "and travelled the total distance of ", travel_dist)
```

What this represents is how many times a ball bounces when dropped from its initial height before it rises to a height of less than 2. You can set the condition of `height` to any number higher than 0 like 0.00001.

Answer (score 0):

```
while height >0  is always true therefore while loop runs infinite.
```

correct the while loop condition by checking count value.

```
while (count>0):
```

Modified Code,

```
height=int(input("Enter the height from which the ball is dropped: "))
count=0
travel_dist=0
index=0.6

if height<=0:
     print("The ball cannot bounce...")
else:
     while (count>0):
        travel_dist=height+(height*index)
        count+=1
        height=height*index
        if height<=0:
           break;

     print("The ball has bounced ", count, "and travelled the total distance of ", travel_dist)
```

Comment: while (count>0) is always false